# Jquery Ajax Call not setting cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I inspected the request and can see that:

```
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.Cookies=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE_Cl-sBAAAAFyzOzXtC90-nkj7osKIxHgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAB68msx5mvbIc_UOFEpHKgyKg8z4X75MKKk5Notp79FeAAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAD8G4ZvSLWFoqp7TVme89yuoX0Kd7V6uYe-WEeeSoYClvAAAAB1vGrXcVvzq7uUYiruKLJiGBpZJBDcOL3PBMRYnHv3VT202hC-4J-U-GGoJlWQz3MrEoq_vmEoE3tbsn09AAX06HZrhBl5ZvyLiTkCcJaAT_xeX-6Uv6fDWMHpezJ_xrhE8nVjOj8oBI2HhIjymzD1CaWCriFqPOQKSoC6OLOHurRUcZ6J8LHeKcsWsc4hm6z6VD-GgzHyHAzZ7OgHX6NMsBpkQ_6VX7e-lo-fUx4RG6sJRIKPHbbFGm8hpfNzFCffbS8nuGC7SMu9zoQLGdDcZx0ulxlQcSxpcfbaaPbb3l1FsM9YZOipQNyLRDQtN-5AAAAA2D6u3avm-yI1tnz-xqBLBus26s2IRF2vuBzDEFkTbG5PPYHY2ijq5-xMzkNlVNsgloQ-XjKhmy9JiX4YLkMSjQ%3D%3D; path=/; expires=Mon, 30-Sep-2013 21:49:58 GMT; HttpOnly
```

but when i look at the browsers cookies, this is not set.

```
$.ajax({
            url: this.path + id,
            beforeSend: (xhr) => this.setAuth(xhr),
            type: 'GET'
        })....
```

Relevant info might be that its a cross origin call. `http://localhost:36859/` to `http://127.255.0.1:8061/` .

Do i need to do anything else to set the cookie?

Comment: of course you cant set a cookie for a different domain/origin check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

Comment: So its not possible when i have my WebAPI hosted at xxx.local and the client at yyy.local, the client ask the server to xxx.local/authenticate and the server sets a cookie containing the userinfo.

Comment: yes its possible, but you have to make sure that `xxx.local/authenticate` sets the cookie with `.local` as the cookie domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    return $.ajax({
        url: this.path + id,
        beforeSend: (xhr) => this.setAuth(xhr),
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    }).fail((xhr, status, error) => {  
        console.log(arguments);           
        notification.showErrorMessage("Error Loading", notification.getErrorDetail(xhr));
    });
```

The xhrFields did the trick. authentication cookie is send along the webapi call.