# Reading response headers in Swagger

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using swagger 2.1.0. I am able to send a header in a request, thanks to [this example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#http-methods-and-api-).

But now my question, the key which is to send with this example-call is received in a header of the previous response. How can I read the headers of the previous response, so I can extract the value to send?

Maybe better, more simple: How can I read the headers which come with a response?

Comment: I could place the code myself if I knew which are the best places. It would be the same places where one would send/receive/manage cookies. Best was when it was injectable in index.html, but for know it would very much please me to put it at the right spot in a lib javascript file. So, it is about sending/receiving/managing headers or cookies (in fact cookies are a special header)  Someone an idea?

Comment: This might be a solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837150/jquery-ajax-call-not-setting-cookie

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie